# WebView en android, ocultar barra de direcciones y que funcione

Tags: android, webview-android

Necesito abrir una web dentro de un WebView sin la barra de direcciones pero tengo dos problemas.

> 1. La web abre perfectamente, pero al hacer clic en algún enlace se queda pantalla en blanco, es decir no puedo navegar.
> 2. Si giro el dispositivo me vuelve a cargar la página principal automáticamente.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
String url="https://miejemplo.com";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.view);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    view.loadUrl(url);
}


private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

     public boolean shouldOverrideUrLoading(WebView view, String url){
        view.loadUrl(url);
         return true; //permite que la página se refresque en el webview
            }
}
```

Gracias

LO HE SOLUCIONADO DE LA SIGUIENTE MANERA:

Para envitar que una actividad de reinicie al girar el dispositivo hay que añadir en el manifiesto AndroidManifest.xml lo siguiente:

android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Por lo que quedaría tal que así:

Comment: Parece que el problema es con ciertas páginas web con login, existe alguna solución conocida para estos casos?

Comment: Eso es que ejecuta un recreate al girar y te vuelve a cargar la página inicial que habías puesto. Mi recomendación es que en el Manifest especifiques que sólo puede tener una orientación o manejar el recreate y especificar que cuando gire, guardar la última url puesta.

Comment: He editado mi pregunta inicial con la respuesta abajo, gracias

Comment: ¿Si te ha servido mi respuesta serías tan amable de votar +1 mi comentario? Gracias.